# zip the pdfs generated in node and download on get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, backend

I want to zip all the files created from the below code at the moment the condition is if length is 1 then it creates one file and download on get request but for same scenario if more than one pdf is created then i need all of them to be zipped in one an download

```
 if (respondentIds.length ===1 ) {
              
            if (!common.isGuid(respondentIds)) {
                log.info(
                    "Invalid respondentId passed",
                    "downloadPdf",
                    null,
                    null,
                    customerId
                );
                let errorMessage = await common.GetErrorMessage(
                    400,
                    localeCode,
                    1,
                    context
                );
                return res.status(400).send({ message: errorMessage });
            }

            let result: any = await respondentExportService.Load(respondentIds, customerId, localeCode, genders, countries);

            if (result && Array.isArray(result) && result?.length == 0) {
                let errorMessage = await common.GetErrorMessage(
                    404,
                    localeCode,
                    1,
                    context
                );
                return res.status(404).send({ message: errorMessage });
            }
            let disclaimerText: any = "KCM";
            let topic = await common.GetLabel(
                "respondentdetail",
                localeCode,
                1,
                context
            );

            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });

            const page = await browser.newPage();

            let headerTemplete = '<div id="header-template" style="font-size:8px !important; color:#808080;padding-left:30px;padding-right:50px"><p><i>{headercontent}</i><p></div>';
            let header = headerTemplete.replace('{headercontent}', topic);
            let footerTemplete = '<div id="footer-template" style="font-size:8px !important; color:#808080;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px"><p><i>{footercontent}</i><p></div>'
            let footer = footerTemplete.replace('{footercontent}', disclaimerText);
            let contenttype = MimeTypes["pdf"];
            let content: any = await this.createTable(result,localeCode,context);
            await page.setContent(content);
            let respondentPdf: Buffer = await page.pdf({
                format: 'A4',
                PreferCSSPageSize: true,
                printBackground: true,
                displayHeaderFooter: true,
                headerTemplate: header,
                footerTemplate: footer,
                margin: {
                    top: 60,
                    bottom: 49,
                    left: 30,
                    right: 30
                }
            });
            await browser.close();

            let base64 = respondentPdf.toString("base64");

            let datetime = moment().format('YYYYMMDD_HHmmss');

            let filename = disclaimerText + datetime + '_' + ".pdf";
            res.writeHead(200, {
                "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename="${filename}"`,
                "Content-Type": contenttype,
                "X-Blob-FileName": filename
            });

            return res.status(200).end(base64);
            }
```

I want   if (respondentIds.length > 1 ) then make pdfs for all different id and finally zip and download on get request. all this to be done in nodejs and express.